# how to count data buyer who had special condition mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

i have data buyer the table called **order_star_member**, on this table contain **createdAt**. that row contain the date of transaction, **users_id** contain the buyer, and **total_price_star_member** was the amount of the transaction of each buyer, so i want to counting the amount of buyer who doing transaction >= 600000 in january and then doing transaction again in february 2020 for >= 600000 too, i tried to make insert new table for january itself and for february itself but it's just wasting time, do you know how exact syntax to solve this problem? i've tried this syntax but idk why the result was 0 instead when i check manual, the answer is 5 buyer who doing transaction in january for >= 600000 transaction and also in february >= 600000

```
select count(*) from (SELECT 
    b.users_id
FROM order_star_member b
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member d
            WHERE d.users_id = b.users_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2019-12-01' AND d.createdAt < '2020-01-01') AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member c
            WHERE c.users_id = b.users_id AND
                  d.createdAt >= '2020-01-01' AND d.createdAt < '2020-02-01') AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member e
                WHERE e.users_id = b.users_id AND d.createdAt < '2019-12-01') group by users_id having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000) inner_query;
```

sample data:

**January**

- A (transaction 100000)
- A (transaction 100000)
- B (transaction 150000)
- B (transaction 600000)

**February**

- A (transaction 500000)
- C (transaction 600000)
- B (transaction 750000)

### Expected Result after doing syntax

- count of buyer who doing transaction >= 600000 in january and february : 1 (B buyer)

---

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.

Comment: done sir, thankyou for your response

Answer (score 2):

If you want users whose sum of the transactions exceeds 600,000 in each of January and February, then you can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select user_id
from (select osm.user_id, month(osm.createdAt) as mon,
             sum(osm.price) as total_price
      from order_star_member osm
      where osm.createdAt >= '2020-01-01' and
            osm.createdAt < '2020-03-01'
      group by osm.user_id, month(osm.createdAt)
     ) um
where total_price >= 600000
group by user_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: thankyou for your resoponse but it still 0, instead when i check manual with select data for new table on january itself, and february itself it count 5 users_id

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not getting 5 is the table alias references arent correct(replacing d with c and e)

```
select count(*) from 
  (SELECT b.users_id FROM order_star_member b WHERE 
        EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member d 
                WHERE d.users_id = b.users_id AND 
                d.createdAt >= '2019-12-01' AND
                d.createdAt < '2020-01-01')
        AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member c 
                WHERE c.users_id = b.users_id AND
                c.createdAt >= '2020-01-01' AND 
                c.createdAt < '2020-02-01') 
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member e
                WHERE e.users_id = b.users_id AND
                e.createdAt < '2019-12-01') 
   group by b.users_id having
   sum(b.total_price_star_member) >= 600000) inner_query;
```

I would work on another group by level to deal with the grouping by month.

Comment: thankyou for your response sir, but when i check it, the result was 104, not 5, maybe i think your syntax not selected in each month i guess.

Comment: Grouping like Gordon says

Comment: Your original query is for December and January not Jan and Feb

Comment: Also can you up vote some of my stuff so my rep goes up so I can comment on others stuff

Comment: can you help me please